# How to solve thi? We are having 6 checkboxes and whenever users select anything we need to call Approval Process provided each checboxes have approver

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

There are like 50 combination I could think of with these 6 checkboxes. Any idea to acheive this. Even with Apex how I can acheive 50 combination. Please help.

```
APAC + Footwear
APAC + Garments
APAC + Gloves
EMEA + Footwear
EMEA + Garments
EMEA + Gloves
Americas + Footwear
Americas + Garments
Americas + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Footwear
APAC + EMEA + Garments
APAC + EMEA + Gloves
APAC + Americas + Footwear
APAC + Americas + Garments
APAC + Americas + Gloves
APAC + Footwear + Garments
APAC + Footwear + Gloves
APAC + Garments + Gloves
EMEA + Americas + Footwear
EMEA + Americas + Garments
EMEA + Americas + Gloves
EMEA + Footwear + Garments
EMEA + Footwear + Gloves
EMEA + Garments + Gloves
Americas + Footwear + Garments
Americas + Footwear + Gloves
Americas + Garments + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Americas + Footwear
APAC + EMEA + Americas + Garments
APAC + EMEA + Americas + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Footwear + Garments
APAC + EMEA + Footwear + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Garments + Gloves
APAC + Americas + Footwear + Garments
APAC + Americas + Footwear + Gloves
APAC + Americas + Garments + Gloves
APAC + Footwear + Garments + Gloves
EMEA + Americas + Footwear + Garments
EMEA + Americas + Footwear + Gloves
EMEA + Americas + Garments + Gloves
EMEA + Footwear + Garments + Gloves
Americas + Footwear + Garments + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Americas + Footwear + Garments
APAC + EMEA + Americas + Footwear + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Americas + Garments + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Footwear + Garments + Gloves
APAC + Americas + Footwear + Garments + Gloves
EMEA + Americas + Footwear + Garments + Gloves
APAC + EMEA + Americas + Footwear + Garments + Gloves
```

[Approval Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mxdo.png)

I tried like this I don't think I can add 50 steps here.Please provide some idea.

Comment: Is there any logic to the combinations or did they just give you an excel with 50 rows. You can continue your way or maybe multi step, like  "America's guy approves first, then emea if any, then APAC if applicable, then gloves ..". Think if it's a job for Queues or using apex to populate 3 hidden lookups on the record and then approval simplifies a lot, will always go to approver1,2,3 regardless of content (some helper object to store the data and apex to look it up?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually with these 6 checkboxes I came up with these combination  and since all these are in same object. It is possible. Any way to acheive it via apex? ANd it is unanimous Approval process so  if combo is APAC + Americas + Footwear all the respective approver should approve

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably load all combinations somewhere, helper object or custom metadata. You can hardcode it in apex but it'll be pain to modify as users join/leave/change departments.

many ways to achieve this, you could think of your checkboxes like 6 bit flags  and that means 2^6 = 64 combinations. So even something as stupid as a list where they key "7" means 000111 = Apac, Garments, Footwear

```
List<List<String>> approvers = new List<List<String>>{
null, // 0 - no approvers = throw error
new List<String>{'Lara'}, // 1 - just 1 approver
```

It won't be very readable... You could take it 1 level up and have a Map<String, List> where key is "EMEA + Gloves" and values are 3 user ids (or names, doesn't matter). It'd be bit more readable. To ensure you can always find an entry you'd have to process checkboxes always in same way as you build your key string.

But really, I'd drag some columns in excel to create all combinations, upload it as custom metadata and then query that object

```
SELECT Approver1__c, Approver2__c, Approver3__c
FROM MyMeta__mdt
WHERE Americas__c = :opp.Americas__c AND EMEA__c = :opp.EMEA__c AND ...
```